# HTML5 drag and drop file, and upload on button click

Tags: html, servlets, drag-and-drop

I have been searching everywhere to find out how to implement the html 5 drag and drop file upload thing and I am still stuck with nothing. I tried BalusC's solution on how to upload the file to a servlet ([HTML5 File Upload to Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114087/html5-file-upload-to-java-servlet)). It works just fine, except that I can't send anything else along with the file. What I'm trying to implement is a form which takes both a file and a textual description of what the file is all about, like a "comment". When the user drags and drops the file, enters the comment and clicks "submit", the file must be uploaded to the server, using Servlets. With BalusC's code, the servlet is invoked, but if I try to display the "comment" (which I appended to the formData object), I get a null value. How can I append the comment to the data I send too? I like Vap0r's implementation too ([HTML5 drag and drop and multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231542/html5-drag-and-drop-and-multiple-file-upload)), but it doesn't work for me either. Help?

Comment: But where is your code, what do you have right now? and if you have problem uploading file maybe you could use filepicker

Comment: please post your code